# Run Django Middleware just once when a session is created?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I wrote a Middleware in Django to do some condition check with user, and add a `Group` to `User (in django.contrib.auth)`'s `groups` field.

I want to show different pages to specific groups of users, using a feature toggle library which uses Django `Group`, so this needs to be done before response. That is why I am doing it in a Middleware.

I am testing it, and it looks like this is done every time there is a request, even an API call.

This seems very wasteful, because this condition check contains a database call and loading a home page involved 5 condition checks, which means five database calls.

I think I only need to do this just once before the user first sees the page. I'm thinking about doing this when a session is created.

Is there any way I can do this? It doesn't need to be in a Middleware, but it has to be before the user sees the webpage.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question but this is a standard feature that is already in Django admin. It's right there when you start a new project in the admin GUI. Users and Groups.

Comment: Why tie it to a session at all? Should it be a different group each session? Otherwise, just do it in the view where the user is created.